# How can I calculate how much a high volume site would save with cloud computing Vs. traditional hosting?

Tags: cloud-computing, analysis

How can I calculate the required bandwith and cost of hosting a site that would have around 3 million unique visitors per year?  I wanted to come up with an estimate of how much cost could be saved by using a cloud computing service like Amazon EC3 vs. using a traditional colocated server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon has a cost calculator to help you estimate these things: http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

Comment: What would be the cost equivalent of hosting it yourself outside of cloud computing?

Answer (score 3):

Roll 3d6 for savings, and 1d20 as a saving throw against not actually saving anything.

Or, to be a little less facetious, there's no guarantee that you'll save anything using EC2.  It depends on your IO, availability, and traffic profiles.  Be careful not to underestimate the hard-to-estimate bits in EC2's cost calculator -- do you know how many IOPS you do to persistent storage each month?  I'll bet it's more than you think.

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate the cost of using traditional hosting
2. Calculate the cost of using cloud hosting
3. Find the difference between #1 and #2

It's very simple in theory, but you're going to have to do the work yourself, we can't do it for you, since it depends on so many variables.